# Bash-script: run another script on bottom as an other user

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron, scripting, root

I have a bash script that runs over crontab as root.

On the bottom of that script I want to run another bash script as another user in a subshell (detached).

How can I do that

The normal command would be

```
/bin/bash /path/myscript.sh
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but something like: `su otheruser -c /path/myscript.sh &` might be a step in the right direction.  Since the main script is running as root, it *should* not require otheruser's password - although doing this thru cron might be a little quirky.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way:

```
/sbin/runuser -l USER -c 'COMMAND'
```

Works :)

Answer (score 0):

`su - USER -c /path/myscript.sh`

Is IMHO the easiest option, it's supposed, that /path/myscript.sh has executable permissions and the typical `#! /bin/bash` first line.